# How do I find the lastest changeset of a branch that was merged into another branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have some anonymous branches in `dev` named branch that eventually will be merged into `default` branch. How do I find the latest changeset of `dev` branch that was already merged into `default` branch?

This is what I came up:

1. I started by showing all the merges in `default` branch:

   ```
   merge() and branch(default)
   ```
2. What I really want is their parents in `dev` branch:

   ```
   parents(merge() and branch(default)) and branch(dev)
   ```
3. That gives me all the `dev` changesets that were merged into `default` branch. Now I just add `max` to get the latest one. This is the final expression:

   ```
   max(parents(merge() and branch(default)) and branch(dev))
   ```

The problem is that I think that this query is too big. Is it possible to get this information with a simpler query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will do it:

```
max(p2(branch(default)) & branch(dev))
```

It gets the changesets on `dev` that are the second parent of a changeset on the `default` branch and the `max` gets the latest one.

It's only one condition shorter though (because the `p2` condition effectively combines the `parent` and `merge` of your query because you can't be the second parent if you're not a merge).

Comment: Now I created these 2 aliases: `.l = log -r "max(p2(branch(default)) & branch(dev))"` and `.u = up -r "max(p2(branch(default)) & branch(dev))"` I use them every time I want to start a new branch in `dev` without beeing affected by other potentially unstable `dev` branches.